# SQL Error [1111] [HY000]: (conn=50) Invalid use of group function

Tags: sql, case

I want to retrieve Total Profit from table, I have used following query but it return invalid use of group function error .What is wrong with my query?

My Query given below,

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
WHEN (sum(t3.amount) - t2.amount) <= 0 
THEN 0 ELSE 
ROUND((sum(t3.amount) - t2.amount),2) END) as 'Profit'
FROM  `tabPurchase Order` as t1
JOIN`tabPurchase Order Item` as t2 ON t1.name  = t2.parent 
JOIN `tabSales Order Item` as t3 ON t1.lot_name = t3.lot_no
WHERE t1.docstatus = 1 AND t3.docstatus = 1 GROUP BY t1.lot_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't group anything that hasnt been selected in your selection clause. The only thing thing you have "selected" from your t1 table is "profit" which is based on a case clause.

In order to group on t1.lot_name, you have to select it as well.
Hope this clears things out for you.

Comment: Without selecting t1.lot_name, I got Profit data. When I try to sum all the profit data, I face this error. If I select t1.lot_name, still face the error

Comment: Yeah you can still aggregate the data that way, but you get the error because you try to group on a column that hasn't been selected.

Comment: Here I select it as well. The sql is like starts with 

`SELECT t1.lot_name`

But still shows the same error. If I misunderstood, can you please specify from the code.  It will be huge help for me

Comment: I need the sum of total profit amount from the row... Is that not possible using group by?

Comment: Can you provide me with the entire query when you also selected t1.lot_name? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's given in my question. Just add the t1.lot_name in the select